# Confusion with time ordering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, time-evolution

I am thinking about [Proof of correlation function formula in quantum field theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223988/proof-of-correlation-function-formula-in-quantum-field-theory) and have realized there is a deeper confusion underpinning that. Consider:

$$T\{U_I(T, t_2)\Phi_I(x_1)\}$$

where $t_2>t_1$ where these are a field operator and the time evolution operator, respectively, both in the Interaction picture.$A=U_I(T, t_2)=T\big\{exp\big(-i\int_{t_2}^{T} dt'\, H_I(t')\big)\big\} = e^{iH_0 (T-t_0)}e^{iH (T-t_2)}e^{iH_0 (t_2-t_0)}$ See [here](http://itp.epfl.ch/webdav/site/itp/users/181759/public/aqft.pdf) for derivation.

Now, the first representation with an integral in the exponent, only has operators (in interaction picture) with time in the interval $(T, t_2) > t_1$, so we find:

\begin{align*}
T\{U_I(T, t_2)\Phi_I(x_1)\} &=T\{T\big\{\exp\big(-i\int_{t_2}^{T} dt'\, H_I(t')\big)\big\}\Phi_I(x_1)\} \\
  &=T\big\{\exp\big(-i\int_{t_2}^{T} dt' H_I(t')\big)\big\}\Phi_I(x_1)=U_I(T, t_2)\Phi_I(x_1)
\end{align*}

However, the second representation has only operators in the Schrodinger picture, which are equal to those operators in the interaction picture, at the arbitrary time $t_0$, which may well be chosen to be less than $t_1$, and so we get:

\begin{align*}
  T\{U_I(T, t_2)\Phi_I(x_1)\} &= T\{e^{i(T-t_0)\cdot H_{I,0}(t_0)}e^{i(T-t_2)\cdot H_I(t_0)}e^{i(t_2-t_0)\cdot H_{I,0}(t_0)}\Phi_I(x_1)\} \\
 &=\Phi_I(x_1)e^{i(T-t_0)\cdot H_{I,0}(t_0)}e^{i(T-t_2)\cdot H_I(t_0)}e^{i(t_2-t_0)\cdot H_{I,0}(t_0)} \\
 &=\Phi_I(x_1)U_I(T, t_2) \neq U_I(T, t_2)\Phi_I(x_1)
\end{align*}

Comment: Operators like $D$ simply do not occur! It maps from one time-mark to two different, unrelated time-marks. The time arguments stem (usually) from the interaction-picture time evolved field operators, so you can at most define $D = AB$ in the Schrödinger picture, then $D(t) = A(t)B(t)$ (i.e. they receive the same time argument).

Comment: Check my edited question where I've put the concrete example I was actually thinking of, and simplified the abstract one even more.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how it is possible to have $A(t_1) = C(t_3)$ with $t_2 > t_3$ while $t_1 > t_2$?!

Comment: Look at the example given. It is not exactly that, but it works the same.

Comment: But in the example given, $A = U(T, t_2)$ has two time variables not one, and $t_1$ does not appear at all! How should I compare it with the original question? I believe your example is not so illustrative. I think you should revise the question before an answer is possible to provide. Do you want to prove $ U_I(T, t_2)= T\big\{exp\big(-i\int_{t_2}^{T} dt' H_I(t')\big)\big\} = e^{iH_0 (T-t_0)}e^{iH (T-t_2)}e^{iH_0 (t_2-t_0)} $?

Comment: Maybe I should delete or edit the "original" question, because my main question is in the example... I know they are not equivalent

Comment: I still fail to see the problem. The correct way to apply time ordering is always in the Taylor expansion of the exponential, this way you can show, that the $T \exp {\int \cdots}$ expression fulfils the time-evolution equation for $U_I$ and then you can show that $U_I$ has the second form stated by evolving a state.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: There is actually no need for a “Taylor expansion” here for the time-ordering; or perhaps, I do not understand what you mean by a Taylor expansion.

Comment: Ok, I removed the "original" question, and left the real question, and tried to make it clearer :P

Comment: @PhilosophiæNaturalis But the exponential of an operator is defined in terms of a series, and you have to write down this series to properly do the time ordering.

Comment: Ok, but in the Taylor expansion, all operators will still be in the interval $(T, t_2)$ right? So the ordering will be what I show on the question?

Comment: @guillefix As I've said: There is no time ordering defined for $U$ only for time-marks on field operators. You have to expand the $\exp$ into a power series and then the time ordering will place $\Phi$ where it belongs. The "outer" time ordering still acts on all individual field operators in the expansion of $U$.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: I see -- that's right. But one does not need that here to prove the relation $U_I(t_2, t_1) = T  \{ \exp [-i \int_{t_1}^{t_2} d t' H_I(t')] \}$. To my knowledge, only a discretization of time and using the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula is needed. In the last step one needs a Taylor expansion in time to show that the error is negligible in the limit of infinitesimal $\Delta t$.

Comment: @SebastianRiese Okk, I know you have to expand it to work it out. Are any of my statements/equations in the question wrong? If so which?

Comment: With the latest edit #3, it became clear what the problem is. So, @SebastianRiese is right: “You have to expand the $\exp$ into a power series...”.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: could you modify the question accordingly, and provide an answer?

Comment: Which of the results for the time ordered product of the $U$ and $\Phi$ is right? 1st, 2nd, or none? If none, I'd indeed like to see the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result is correct. Time ordering acts on interaction picture field operators. $H_I(t)$ is to be understood as a function of interaction picture field operators at time $t$.

The representation
$$ U(t, t') = e^{iH_0t}e^{-iH(t - t')}e^{-iH_0t} $$
does not represent $U$ in terms of interaction picture field operators and is therefore not permissible. Only because the operators are the same at that instant does not mean you can use them as interaction picture operators. The point here is, that the time-marks occur also explicitly, while the time dependence has to be implicit as the time dependence of the field operators for the technique to work.

To correctly evaluate expressions involving time ordering one has to expand the exponential and time order every term:
$$ T\left\{\exp \left(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}dt\,H(t) \right) \phi(t_3) \right\} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n!} \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt'_1 \cdots \int_{t_1}^{t_2} dt'_n T H(t'_1) \cdots H(t'_n)\phi(t_3).$$
If now $t_3 < t_1 < t_3$ the operator $\phi(t_3)$ will always be ordered to the right, and therefore can be factored out to the right and so the result is the time evolution operator followed by $\phi(t_3)$.

Comment: Ok, so you have to express operators in interaction picture to apply the time ordering. Thanks

Comment: Btw, if you could give a hand with the related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223988/ that'd be cool!